# Issue with Array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach

I am new to Perl and now have an issue with below array processing in Perl.

```
while ( ($stu_id,$gate_nbr) = $cursor->fetchrow() )
{
    foreach my $stu_details (@stu_dbs)
    {
        my($stu_no,$sch_id,$lnk_svr_tx) = @$stu_details;
        if ($stu_no == $stu_id)
        {
            SortSchRec($stu_no,$gate_nbr,$sch_id,$sch_tx);
        }
    }
    $log->writeI("Stud ID:". $stu_id );
    $log->writeI("Gate ID:". $gate_nbr);
}

$cursor->finish();
```

the above code processes the first array value, but doesnt pick the next array value. Can you let me know what is the issue with this foreach statement and how to fix it?

Comment: No apparent issue with the loop. Either the array actually has one element, or `SortSchRec()` does something unexpected.  Did you print `@stu_dbs`?  (There are modules for showing complex data -- I use `Data::Dump` with its `dd` and `pp`, the `Data::Dumper` is core, there are others.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks zdim, i figured out the issue.. had already opened a cursor in previous function as global variable, but introduced this one in between.. changed the cursor variable name and now im able to execute the script.